# Mapping Key_on parameter on Folium

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geojson, folium, choropleth

I want to map the key_on parameter for tokyo_map

Here is my dataframe:

```
                Area    Municipality    Positive Cases  id
0   Special ward area   Adachi Ku     4769  13121
1   Special ward area   Arakawa Ku    1591  13118
2   Special ward area   Itabashi Ku   3683  13119
3   Special ward area   Edogawa Ku    3853  13123
4   Special ward area   Ota Ku        5255  13111
5   Special ward area   Katsushika Ku 2898  13122
6   Special ward area   Kita Ku       2204  13117
7   Special ward area   Koto Ku       3279  13108
8   Special ward area   Shinagawa Ku  3033  13109
9   Special ward area   Shibuya Ku    3014  13113
```

My geo_json file for tokyo is as follows.

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',
 'crs': {'type': 'name',
  'properties': {'name': 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::900913'}},
 'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
   'properties': {'ward_ja': '足立区',
    'ward_en': 'Adachi Ku',
    'area_ja': '都区部',
    'area_en': 'Tokubu',
    'code': 131211},
   'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [[[139.821051, 35.815077],
      [139.821684, 35.814887],
```

I want to map municipality in Dataframe to ward_en in geojson file.
But I am unable to do that.

Here is my choropleth code.

```
tokyo_map.choropleth(
    geo_data = tokyo_geojson,
    data=df_tokyo,
    columns=['Municipality', 'Positive Cases'],
    key_on = 'features.properties.ward_en',
    fill_color='BuPu',
    threshold_scale=threshold_scale,
    fill_opacity=0.6, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Corona Cases in Tokyo',
    highlight = True,
    reset=True
)

tokyo_map
```

I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause, but the names of the municipalities in the dataframe are different from geojson. `Adachi <> Adati Ku`.

Comment: hii @r-beginners 
 i modified my dataframe but still getting the same error can you help me please

Comment: I tried to reproduce your question and probably encountered the same challenge. For example, if I write the data for Adachi ward only in the code, the map will be created correctly. Could you please share the geojson link to confirm?

Comment: There was one more correction. `key_on='feature.properties.ward_en'` This is correct.

Comment: https://github.com/jassu1290/Coursera_Capstone/blob/main/tokyo.geojson          **Thank you so much** for helping me @r-beginners here is the geo_json file

Comment: Did the map show up?

Comment: yes i finally sloved the problem. Thank you

Comment: Why don't you self-answer? For future Folium users.